# checking another table for a field status eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay I have a custom field name is_friend

I have 3 tables
1. Users
2. Workers
3. Friends

As you guess a worker belongs to a user, a friend belongs to a worker.

My query, I want to check whether if a worker is **a friend of** the current signed in user

Friends schema:

```
    Schema::create('tweets', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('targetID');
        $table->integer('ownerID');
        $table->timestamps();
    }
```

As you can see from the schema, the targetID is the friend id of the worker, ownerID is the signed in user.

My query:

```
$worker = Worker::get('name');
```

Inside my worker's model

```
class Worker extends Eloquent{

    protected $appends = array('is_friend');

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }

    public function getIsFriendAttribute(){
        if(Friend::where('targetID', $this->attributes['id'])
            ->where('ownerID', Auth::user()->id)->first()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I am using a custom accessor to get this custom field.
It works but it is pretty ugly, If i query 20 workers, there will be **20 queries just to check this status.**

On view, i can access like

```
@if($worker->is_friend)
   Your friend
@endif
```

Comment: How do you query 20 workers?

Comment: Hi @MarcinNabiałek for now i am doing `Worker::get('name')`, it will get all of the worker table rows out since I am not using any limit or where. So if there is 20 rows, 20 will be outputted, thus another 20 just to check each row for this status.

Comment: There is a `hasManyThrough` method for this kind of relations but I'm not sure if it would accomplish what you want. I'll send an answer if  I can test it any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think this issue(the n+1 problem) can be solved using eager loading with constraints.

First define a friends relation in the Worker Model . 
as such

```
class Worker extends Eloquent{
    ...
    // This will get all the friends
    public function friends(){
        return $this->hasMany('Friend','targetID');
    }
    ...

}
```

We use eager loading to deal with the n +1 problem. [Click here and scroll down to Eager Load Constraints for documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
// We use Eager loading constraints so that only two db queries are executed instead of n+1
$workers = Worker::with(array('friends' => function($query)
{
    // So we constraint the ownerId to be current user id
    $query->where('ownerID', Auth::user()->id);

}))->get();
```

Now on the view

```
@foreach ($workers as $worker)
    @if(count($worker->friends) >0)
    Your friend
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I have a question if I use this only workers with friends will be obtained? how about those that do not have friends. I want to get a mixed results of workers that are friends with the user and not. and if they are friends, there will be a field to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following relation to your `Worker` model:

```
public function friendsNumber()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Friend','targetID')
        ->selectRaw('targetID, count(targetID) as count')
        ->where('ownerID', Auth::user()->id)
        ->groupBy('targetID');            
}
```

and now add the following accessor to the `Worker` model:

```
public function getIsFriendAttribute()
{
    if (!array_key_exists('friendsNumber', $this->relations)) {
        $this->load('friendsNumber');
    }
    $related = $this->getRelation('friendsNumber')->first();
    return ($related && $related->count) ? true : false;
}
```

now you should be able to use:

$workers = Worker::with('friendNumber')->get();

```
foreach ($workers as $worker) {
  echo $worker->name;
  if ($worker->is_friend) {
     echo " is your friend";
  }
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: There's no `count` method on the `$related` called this way - either check for `null` only or don't use `first` line above. **Or** use `hasOne` instead of course.